# background image hover fade in effect

Tags: css

my code i add fade hover effect but this is not working when i call image in css background properties. this is my code:-

```
<ul class="submenu-one submenu menu-toggle">
      <li><a href="#">at a glance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vision and Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">our history</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">our strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">board members</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Css:-

```
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0% {opacity:1;}
45% {opacity:1;}
55% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}    
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu-one { position: absolute; top:21px; left: 320px; z-index: 2; background: #000000; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu li{ list-style: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px;}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu li > a{display: block; padding: 49px 80px 50px 21px; color: #ffffff; min-width: 319px; text-decoration: none;}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu-one li:nth-child(1) > a:hover{
    background:url(../images/sub-menu-img1.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu-one li:nth-child(2) > a:hover{background:url(../images/sub-menu-img2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu-one li:nth-child(3) > a:hover{background:url(../images/sub-menu-img3.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu-one li:nth-child(4) > a:hover{background:url(../images/sub-menu-img4.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;}
#menu > ul li > ul.submenu-one li:nth-child(5) > a:hover{background:url(../images/sub-menu-img5.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;}
```

we edit some code please check the update code in below link

here is jsfiddle link:- https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/ye45gv7y/

Comment: your posted HTML is not complete. in CSS i see you have 2 levels of `ul`, but in html only one

Comment: the fiddle console shows that the file wasn't found...

Comment: Please check the first menu (About Group) sub menu, we add the bg color red rider then image